# how to delete rows from mysql database not found in xml file

Tags: php, mysql, xml

I have an xml file and now it's been inserted to MySQL database, but there was a problem in the xml file which meant some data may be deleted from the site, so I updated the xml file and I wrote code for deleting data from database table which deleted from xml but the records are still in the database.

from another way I want to compare between xml file and database and delete data not found.

```
<?php

    ini_set('display_errors','On');
    //connecting to database.
    echo "connected to DB<br /><br />";


    $url = "test.xml";
    $xmlfgc = file_get_contents($url);
    $xmlitem = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlfgc);
    echo "xml loaded<br /><br />";

    foreach ($xmlitem->property as $xml) {
        //$id          = mysql_real_escape_string($xml->id);              
        $mls_id      = mysql_real_escape_string($xml->ref);         

        //echo "$mls_id";
        echo "xml parsed<br /><br />";            

         $result = mysql_query("SELECT mls_id FROM ezrealty");


       //$select = "SELECT mls_id FROM ezrealty";
       //$storeArray = Array();
       //while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
       //     $storeArray[] =  $row['mls_id'];  
       //}

        if ($result != $mls_id){    
            $query = "DELETE FROM ezrealty WHERE mls_id = '$mls_id'";
            mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
            echo "DataBase deleted<br /><br />";
    }else{                          
            echo "There is no deleted properties from xml file.";        
        }                  
    }

       //show updated records 
       echo "<br /><br />";
       printf ("Records updated: %d\n", mysql_affected_rows());  

    //close connection 
    mysql_close($con2);

?>
```

Comment: How does your xml file looks like? Can you post a sample from it?

Comment: I such a situation I would load the new XML file into a temp table, then do a DELETE based on a LEFT OUTER JOIN between your existing table and the new table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for you, now i have the solution for my problem.

```
<?php

    ini_set('display_errors','On');
    //connecting to database.
    echo "connected to DB<br /><br />";


    $url = "test.xml";
    $xmlfgc = file_get_contents($url);
    $xmlitem = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlfgc);
    echo "xml loaded<br /><br />";

    $xmldata = array();
    foreach ($xmlitem->property as $xml) {               

       $mls_id      = mysql_real_escape_string($xml->ref);                

       // $xmldata[] = "$mls_id";
       $xmldata[] = '("' . $mls_id. '")';     
    }

    //Get all reference numbers from database in array     
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT mls_id FROM gitfd_ezrealty");
    $storeArray = Array();
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
          $storeArray[] =  $row['mls_id'];  
     }

    //get difference between two arrays.     
    $result1 = array_diff($xmldata, $storeArray);   
    foreach ($result1 as $value) {
        //echo "<strong>$value</strong> <br />";
        //$value1 = '("' . $value. '")';
        //$query = 'INSERT INTO gitfd_ezrealty (mls_id)
        //VALUES' . implode(',', $value1);    
        //mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

        //echo "inserted into mysql<br /><br />";
    }
    echo "These properties are founded in target site and Not founded in our site.<br />";
    echo "________________________________________________________________"."<br />";
    print_r($result1);
    echo "<br />"."_____________________________________________________________________"."<br />";


   $result2 = array_diff($storeArray, $xmldata);
    foreach ($result2 as $value) {
           //echo "<strong>$value</strong> <br />"; 
           $query = "DELETE FROM ezrealty WHERE mls_id = '$value'";
            mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
            echo "DataBase deleted<br /><br />";
    }    
    echo "_________________________________________________________________"."<br />";
    print_r($result2);
    echo "<br />"."______________________________________________________________________"."<br />";
    echo "These properties were deleted .<br />";

       //show updated records 
       echo "<br /><br />";
       printf ("Records updated: %d\n", mysql_affected_rows());  

    //close connection 
    mysql_close($con2);

?>
```